# Console.WriteLine repeating itself for some reason

Tags: c#, recursion, console.writeline

I'm an absolute beginner in C# and have written this code, and the output is making me confused:

```
static void PlayerInfo() //Asking information about the player
    {
        Console.Write("Type your name: ");
        string inputName = Console.ReadLine();

        if (inputName.Length < 2)
            PlayerInfo();
        else
            playerName = inputName;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello " + playerName + "!");
    }
```

If I type J first, it will ask me again till I type at least 2 characters. And if I type John Doe afterwards, it will give me this output twice `Console.WriteLine("Hello " + playerName + "!");`

I don't understand why, It looks like this in the console:

```
Type your name: J         //The length is smaller than 2
Type your name: John Doe  //Restart the function and type a valid length
Hello John Doe!           //This is OK
Hello John Doe!           //Why a second print?
```

It's probably not the best practice to use a recursive method. I'm doing it just to learn the language.

Comment: It is printing twice because of the recursion. If you step through it you will see that.

Comment: Each recursive call will need to end ; When your "inner" PlayerInfo end the code "backtracks" to the previous call and do what's next ; If you input J twice before valid input ; the message'll show 3 times. You should try to debug step by step (or by hand) to understand why better

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: When you type J you reenter the code a second time. Now typing two letters allow you to exit from the PlayerInfo method but the code resumes from where you left when you typed a J and prints again before exiting. Recursion 101.

Comment: Try to implement a **Fibonacci Sequence** recursive method.  That's a better way to learn about recursive methods.

Comment: A `PlayerInfo()` always ends with a `Console.WriteLine()`. Since you call `PlayerInfo()` twice, I think you can see why it happens.

Comment: Where are you declaring {playerName}? This code won't compile.

Comment: @wdosanjos It's an *awful* problem to try to solve using recursion.  Unless your recursive solution is using caching, in which case it'll be way more memory intensive than an iterative solution, it's turning an O(n) operation into an O(2^n) operation.  It's a problem that's very much *not* well set up for an (effective) recursive implementation.

Comment: @ChrisZimmerman It's a field.

Comment: @Servy I didn't mean to say it's the best approach to solve the Fibonacci Sequence problem, but it's simple for one to learn about recursion.

Comment: @wdosanjos No, it's not.  If you want to learn how to use recursion effectively you want to be using it in situations where it's actually an appropriate solution to the problem, else you end up learning bad habits about how to actually use it appropriately, or end up thinking that it's just not an effective tool in general, all because your "great example of when to use recursion" was providing an awful example of a situation to use recursion.  If you want to provide an example of how to learn recursion, then provide an example where recursion is actually a good solution for the problem.

Comment: @Servy OK. what is a good problem to learn about recursion then? Towers of Hanoi?

Comment: @wdosanjos Sure, that's a fine problem to solve using recursion, or many tree traversal problems, for example, are rather difficult to solve iteratively and are extremely effectively solved recursively. (Assuming the tree isn't overly tall.)

Comment: FYI [Fibonacci Sequence Calculation C#](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_the_Fibonacci_sequence#C.23), [Towers of Hanoi C#](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Towers_of_Hanoi#C.23).

Comment: `if (inputName.Length < 2) { PlayerInfo(); return; }`

Comment: Tower of Hanoi isn't a great problem either, because (1) there is an easy non-recursive solution. (Number the disks, never move an odd disk onto another odd disk or an even onto an even, never undo a move you just made.) and (2) it's an unrealistic problem.  Pick a realistic problem that can be solved with recursion, eg, what is the height of this binary tree, quicksort this list, etc.

Comment: Remember that recursion is only useful when (1) there is a minimal problem  that can be solved easily (2) a larger problem can be reduced to a set of strictly smaller problems whose solutions can be combined, and (3) recursion always terminates at a minimal problem. Your example here does not have the required characteristics, so don't use recursion. Use loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue occurs because of the recursion.
You call `PlayerInfo()` two times so you get the output twice, it's as simple as that.
If you'd typed "A", then "B", then "John" you'd get the output 3 times and so on.

The answer is to take out the recursion. If you wish to keep prompting until you receive a valid input then one solution is a `while` loop:

```
void Main()
{
    PlayerInfo();
}

static void PlayerInfo()
{
    string inputName = string.Empty;

    // This will loop until inputName is longer than 2 characters
    while (inputName.Length < 2)
    {
        Console.Write("Type your name: ");
        inputName = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Now that inputName is longer than 2 characters it prints the result only once
    Console.WriteLine("Hello " + inputName + "!");
}
```

Example:

> Type your name: A
>   Type your name: B
>   Type your name: John
>   Hello John!

[See it working on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S2JSSv)

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the issue is with recursion.

I'm assuming that `playerName`is being declared outside of this method.
What's happening is that `playerName` is getting properly assigned on your second call.
Since the variable is at a class level, the value is preserved and printed on your outermost call as well.
Since that call went through the `if (inputName.Length < 2)` branch of your condition, thus not reassigning the value of `playerName`.